# MYSQL. Расстановка значения в одной таблице по признаку в другой таблице

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет.

**Таблица_1 RECEPT.**
Есть таблица RECEPT в которой есть столбец OPISANIE_RECEPT, а также есть столбец CATEGORIA

```
OPISANIE_RECEPT    | CATEGORIA
------------------------------
Возьмите морковь...| NULL
Почистить яблоко...| NULL
```

**Таблица_2  PRIZNAK_CAT.**
Таблица PRIZNAK_CAT, которая содержит два поля, это признак и сама категория. Ну например:

```
PRIZNAK  | CAT
-----------------
морковь  | овощи
буряк    | овощи
яблоко   | фрукты
```

Мне нужно написать SQL запрос который в первой таблице в поле, где написан рецепт будет искать наличие слова-признака из второй таблицы и при первом совпадении будет подставлять категорию из второй таблицы в полек категории первой таблицы.

На выходе рассчитываю получить таблицу RECEPT

```
OPISANIE_RECEPT    | CATEGORIA
------------------------------
Возьмите морковь...| овощи
Почистить яблоко...| фрукты
```

Прошу помощи.
PS
Надеюсь я Вас не запутал, заранее благодарю.

Comment: *и при первом совпадении будет подставлять категорию из второй таблицы в полек категории первой таблицы* Поясните, нужно просто получать требуемое значение в запросе, или необходимо заполнить значениями (обновить) поле CATEGORIA?

Comment: Как результат, таблица RECEPT должна обновится и поля CATEGORIA равные NULL должны иметь значения CAT полученные из таблицы признаков.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT R.OPISANIE_RECEPT, P.CAT
FROM RECEPT AS R
JOIN PRIZNAK_CAT AS P
ON R.OPISANIE_RECEPT LIKE CONCAT('%', P.PRIZNAK, '%');
```

Но при этом производительность у запроса на больших объёмах данных будет очень плохая, потому что используется поиск слова в середине строки.

Если важна производительность, то следует вместо `LIKE` использовать `MATCH` и добавить полнотекстовый индекс по полю `R.OPISANIE_RECEPT`.

Comment: Вы не обратили внимание на слова *при первом совпадении*. Ваш запрос решает задачу "при любом из имеющихся" - не обязательно первом по тексту.

Answer (score 0):

Я благодарю Rugabarbo, который натолкнул меня на мысль. Вот вариант моего решения:

```
UPDATE RECEPT
SET RECEPT.CATEGORIA = 
(
  SELECT  PRIZNAK_CAT.CAT   FROM PRIZNAK_CAT
  WHERE RECEPT.OPISANIE  
  LIKE CONCAT ('%', PRIZNAK_CAT.PRIZNAK, '%') 
  LIMIT 1
);
```

Буду благодарен за любые комменты, подсказки.

Comment: Комментарий тот же - если одному OPISANIE соответствуют несколько PRIZNAK, то в таблицу попадёт не первое по тексту, а случайное из возможных.